# Sum multiple groups in the having clause

Tags: sql-server, having-clause

I have the following query that display counts by insurance type.  This is the query:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by PatInfo.PatientProfileID Order By E.Visit desc) AS RowNumber, 
        PatInfo.PatientProfileID, E.Visit, PatInfo.Zip, E.CarrierTypeDesc, E.FinancialClassDescription, IG.UDSInsuranceGroupName,IG.UDSInsuranceID
FROM Encounter E JOIN CHCEncounterType ET ON E.CHCEncounterTypeID = ET.CHCEncounterTypeID       
        JOIN PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UDSInsuranceMapping ON ISNULL(dbo.UDSInsuranceMapping.InsuranceName,'') = ISNULL(E.FinancialClassDescription,'') 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UDSInsuranceGroups IG ON IG.UDSInsuranceID = dbo.UDSInsuranceMapping.UDSInsuranceID            
WHERE E.EncounterCounted = 1 
) 

SELECT Zip AS ZipCode, 
    Count(PatientProfileID) as Total, UDSInsuranceGroupName, UDSInsuranceID
from CTE 
where RowNumber = 1 AND ZIP IS NOT NULL 
group by Zip, UDSInsuranceGroupName, UDSInsuranceID
```

An example of the zip code data returned is as follows:

```
Zip Code  Total InsuranceGroup             InsuranceID 
19522       9   Medicaid/CHIP/Other/Public      2 
19522       1   Medicare                        3 
19522       1   None/Uninsured                  1 
19522       1   Private                         4
19512       2   Medicaid/CHIP/Other/Public      2
19512       1   None/Uninsured                  1
19518       1   Medicaid/CHIP/Other/Public      2
19518       1   Medicare                        3
```

I would like to limit display to only the zip codes that total more than 10.
So the zip code `19522` would be displayed because there are 12 but the other would not be displayed.
If I add a `having` clause the 19522 zip is not displayed because there are only 9 in one of the insurance categories.  I need to sum all of the insurance categories per zip code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use window functions, but this requires another level of subquery:

```
with . ..
select *
from (select Zip AS ZipCode, 
             Count(*) as Total, UDSInsuranceGroupName,
             UDSInsuranceID,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by zip) as zipTotal
      from CTE 
      where RowNumber = 1 AND ZIP IS NOT NULL 
      group by Zip, UDSInsuranceGroupName, UDSInsuranceID 
     ) z
where zipTotal > 10;
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by PatInfo.PatientProfileID Order By E.Visit desc) AS RowNumber, 
            COUNT(0)OVER(PARTITION BY PatInfo.PatientProfileID) AS ZipTotalCount, 
            PatInfo.PatientProfileID, E.Visit, PatInfo.Zip, E.CarrierTypeDesc, E.FinancialClassDescription, IG.UDSInsuranceGroupName,IG.UDSInsuranceID
    FROM Encounter E JOIN CHCEncounterType ET ON E.CHCEncounterTypeID = ET.CHCEncounterTypeID       
            JOIN PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID
            LEFT JOIN dbo.UDSInsuranceMapping ON ISNULL(dbo.UDSInsuranceMapping.InsuranceName,'') = ISNULL(E.FinancialClassDescription,'') 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.UDSInsuranceGroups IG ON IG.UDSInsuranceID = dbo.UDSInsuranceMapping.UDSInsuranceID            
    WHERE E.EncounterCounted = 1 
    ) 

    SELECT Zip AS ZipCode, ZipTotalCount,
        Count(PatientProfileID) as Total, UDSInsuranceGroupName, UDSInsuranceID
    from CTE 
    where RowNumber = 1 AND ZIP IS NOT NULL AND ZipTotalCount>10
    group by Zip, UDSInsuranceGroupName, UDSInsuranceID,ZipTotalCount
```